# ajax data not received by Net Core controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a pretty basic ajax call with a json data object. The request gets to my controller but with out the data.

Ajax

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'Playlist/AttachVideoToPlaylist',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": tokenSet['requestToken']
            },
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "videoId": videoId,
                "playlistId": listId
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            } 
        });
```

That goes to this method, which for now is pretty basic

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<JsonResult> AttachVideoToPlaylist([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
}
```

the `data` parameter is empty. I don't know whether my data object in the ajax request is empty, but when I test

```
JSON.stringify({
      "videoId": videoId,
      "playlistId": listId
})
```

in a `console.log()` it works fine.
What am I missing here? --> Solved.

Edits (Solution):
Rena's answer fixed my issue. Adding the reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` as a library and the addition to `startup.cs` made it work.

Comment: Look at the network tab in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: not much is happening there, and neither in Console. Network tab returns 200 code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in a console.log() it works fine. What am I missing here?

That is because no matter you receive null or not null data in backend,it will always return a Json `success = true`.So it will be always get 200 Status code.

What @Sergey did is a good workaround,but it may not resolve and explain your original problem for why `JObject` receives null value.

The reason for `JObject` get null data,it may because you used asp.net core 3.x or 5.0.`JObject` is used in **Json.Net**.And it has been removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework since asp.net core 3.0.

To meet your requirement,you could add Newtonsoft support:

1.Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package.

2.Update `Startup.ConfigureServices` to call `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Then what you could receive the data and get the ids like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> AttachVideoToPlaylist([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    var videoId = data["videoId"].ToString(); //if it is a string
    var playlistId =(int) data["playlistId"];  //if it is an integer
    return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I use Net Core 3.1 for my project, so adding the reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Fix ajax

```
 $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/Playlist/AttachVideoToPlaylist',
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": tokenSet['requestToken']
            },
             data: {
                VideoId: videoId,
                PlaylistId: listId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            } 
        });
```

Create VideViewModel class:

```
public class VideoViewModel
{

public int VideoId { get; set;}
public int PlaylistId { get; set;}

}
```

and fix your action:

```
[Route("~/Playlist/AttachVideoToPlaylist")]
public async Task<JsonResult> AttachVideoToPlaylist(VideViewModel model)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
}
```

If it is still doesn't work , replace headers of your ajax with this:

```
 beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                        "Bearer " + tokenSet['requestToken']);
                },
```